# Taylor Series of $e^{-1/x^2}$ about $0$

Tags: taylor-expansion

> So I worked out the Taylor series of $e^{-1/x^2}$ about $0$. However, all derivatives at $0$ came out to be $0$. So how can we write the Taylor series of the above function about $0$?

Comment: The Taylor series is just zero.

Comment: You've correctly computed the formal expansion.  As you have noticed, it does not converge to  the actual function (other than at $x=0$).

Comment: So what does Taylor series being 0 mean ? Does that mean we can't approximate every function with a polynomial ?

Comment: @user3650050 you can use other points, read about radius of convergence of Taylor series. Also this function is not analytic

Comment: @user3650050 Exactly, we can’t approximate every function by a polynomial.

Comment: Actually, [$f(x)=0$ approximates it quite well](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rxh78wckyg)...

Comment: Actually, the zero polynomial is approximating pretty well the function near $0$, in fact, for each degree $n$, it is **the best polynomial approximation using a polynomial of degree at most $n$** since the discrepancy is $O(x^{n+1})$ when $x\to0$.

Answer (score 1):

We're going to prove that the function 
$$f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
e^{-1/x^2} & \text{if } x\neq 0 \\
0 & \text{if } x=0
\end{array}
\right.$$
is infinitely differentiable and all his derivatives at $x=0$ are zero.

By induction, it's easy to check that, if $x\neq 0$, for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we have
$$f^{n)}(x)=\frac{e^{-1/x^2}P_{2n-2}(x)}{x^{3n}},$$
where $P_{2n-2}(x)$ is a polynomial with degree $2n-2$, and if $x=0$ 
$$f^{n)}(0)=0. $$

Then, we can apply Taylor's Theorem. However, as $f^{n)}(0)=0$ for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, the Taylor Series is just $0$.

Answer (score -1):

As you worked out, the Taylor series of this function is 0. It means that, around 0, this function and all of its derivatives evaluate to 0.

Answer (score -2):

@user3650050 : I suppose that you expect a series which approximates the function $y(x)=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{x^2} \right)$ for $x$ close to $0$.

The pertinent comments and answer that you already received might disappoint you because whey don't give an approximate series as expected : As already pointed out, the Taylor series for $y(x)=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{x^2} \right)$ at $x=0$ doesn't fit the function for $x$ not exactly $0$.

I don't know if the next form of series can be useful for you, but I hope so :

Around $x=\epsilon\:\:$ close to $0$, the first terms of the series expansion are :
$$\exp\left(-\frac{1}{x^2} \right)=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{\epsilon^2} \right)\left(1+\frac{2}{\epsilon^3}x +\frac{2-3\epsilon^2}{\epsilon^6}x^2 +\frac{\frac43 -6\epsilon^2+4\epsilon^4}{\epsilon^9}x^3 +... \right)$$

Comment: "there is no explicit form of Taylor series" Sorry? There is a quite explicit Taylor series, only, its sum does not coincide with the value of the function.

Comment: Everybody  understand what I mean.  Let's not play too much on words. Nevertheless, I correct it for you.

Comment: "Everybody understand[s] what I mean" Who says so? You are on a site full of beginners, hence imprecisions (or squarely wrong assertions) are **not** ok.

Comment: My dear Did : I congratulate you for your immense zeal about the precision of what is written here, for the benefit of all of us.

Comment: Just post accurate statements, and all will be well. Omitting the heavy tries of humor would be a plus, naturally, but this point, contrary to the first one, is not mandatory.